# Determine the user’s location and translate error messages

Tags: java, javafx

I'm not sure if this is possible off-hand so bear with me. I'm trying to use no external API calls from Java and determine the users language and somehow show translated strings.

Is this something you can do in Java without getting the data from online or something similar? I'm trying to make it available as an offline application but I just don't know how.

Edit:
I'm looking for a way to check with only the standard Java API's

Comment: The user's preferred language can be accessed as `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()`, if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
 LanguageTest lt = new LanguageTest();
 System.out.println(lt.getGreeting());

 private class LanguageTest{
    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toLowerCase();

    public String getGreeting(){
        return (lang.contains("fr") ? "Bonjour" : "Hello");
    }

}
```

In the above example if the language is not french it will default to english.

Comment: I'd suggest using resource bundles instead of hardcoding likes this though.